# function for directly refering to variables instead of dataset$variable in R

Tags: r, variables, variable-assignment

there is a function that lets you refer to the variables just by the variable name, instead of having to type dataset$variable you have a function:

```
xxx(dataset)
```

and afterward, you can just use the variable names.

I have used this function a million times, but cannot remember the name, nor find it on the internet. Thanks !

so instead of doing :

```
variable1 <- dataset$variable1
variable2 <- dataset$variable2
variable3 <- dataset$variable3
```

i just call the function:

```
xxx(dataset)
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean. Do you mean a function `xxx` that returns `variable1` or `variable2` or `variable3`, all columns in a frame `dataset` ... and knows which one to pull? Or do you mean making `dataset1$all_column_names` available as individual variables in the calling environment?

Comment: If the latter, then try `attach(dataset)`, after which you can do `variable1` and see it as a vector (or, in non-standard conditions, a `list`). While this does make it a little more convenient, I warn that it can be confusing at times where things are located and where they can be assigned (programmatically, with-reproducibility, while troubleshooting, and for others looking at your code).

Comment: Note that if opting to use `attach(dataset)`, one should always end by using `detach(dataset)`. And that the same dataset can be attached multiple times, making one have to detach it multiple times. If you save your workspace this may cause problems if one forgets to `detach(dataset)` until the dataset is no longer attached.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `with(dataset, { expression } )` where expression can be any length of code.